# How can I redefine styles with css modules?

Tags: css, css-modules

I use library that used css modules within, and styles come to browser with hash, how could I redefine this styles?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: @ImanAmini Hi sure, I have the library that gives me react component, so I see inside browser styles like  NotificationBase__icon__pNwNg, with hash ending, so I don't know how to redefine this NotificationBase__icon. Probably I miss something obvious

Comment: I think my question is applicable, can't find out how to solve this issue, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the answer on this topic is that paradigm of css modules dictate us behavior that doesn't imply overriding styles in other component, that supposed to be correct component approach to design interface and  protect our production code from unexpected bugs. However if we need to enrich our component with styles from another component we can provide this by drilling props and can adjust this accordingly, e.g. we can check which styles come from the props and filter them out of the wrong ones, e.g. from 'position: absolute'.

upd:
and actually great article on that: https://liefery-it-legacy.github.io/blog/2018/06/27/overriding-styles-with-CSS-modules.html